# Build.gradle file setup

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, build.gradle, android-proguard

I am hitting the following issue. I am new to editing the guild.gradle or the proguard files.

```
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Following are list of features I need from google play services. I have the google play version version 7571000.

1. Admob Ads
2. Analytics
3. IAP

Could you please let me know the setup I need to have in build.gradle and proguard files ? Also Please throw some light on build.gradle and proguard files

I have added this in my build.gradle. I still have the same issue:

```
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Here are my libs dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.+' 
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.+' 
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.5.+' 
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.5.+' 
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:7.5.+' 
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-common:7.5.+' 
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.5.+' 
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.+' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is seems like you have over 65K methods to do in your app. In  this case you need to use `MultiDex`.

You can read about using `MulltiDex` in your app here [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Also you can separate your `GPS`, like this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
```

Comment: I need to support the lower version of Android OS as well. Just stripping the unwanted methods from google play services will do

Comment: @iappmaker MulltiDex has no min level api, so you can use it on all versions of android

Comment: Check "Limitations of the multidex support library" in https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#avoid

Comment: @iappmaker I see avoid, but no limitations. In case when you cant avoid 65k methods, you have to use MultiDex.
Also... You can choose only parts of GPS, that you need in your app. 

Watch my answear update

Comment: @iappmakera Then you can do nothing but use `MulltiDex`. It is normal practice in big apps.